# Java - AWS - too many files open

Tags: java, amazon-s3, amazon-web-services

I'm using the java AWS SDK in order to download a big amount of files from one S3 bucket, edit the files, and copy them back to a different S3 bucket.

I think it's supposed to work fine, but there is one line that keeps throwing me exceptions:

when I use

```
    myClient.getObject(myGetObjectRequest, myFile)
```

I get an AmazonClientException saying there are too many files open.

Now, each time I download a file, edit it and copy it back to the bucket, I delete the temporary files I create.
I'm assuming it's taking a few milliseconds to delete the file, and maybe that's why I'm getting these errors.
Or is it maybe because of the open files on Amazon's side?

Anyway, I made my application sleep for 3 seconds each time it encounters this exception, that way it would have time to close the files, but that just takes too much time. Even if I'll take it down to 1 second.

Has anybody encountered this problem?
What should I do?

Thanks

Comment: Is this on linux?  Look at increasing the limit, google for ulimit

Comment: Yeah, it's on Linux. I'll check it out (Although I'd really rather not mess around with the OS settings...). Thanks.

Comment: I've seen this problem before on AWS and ulimit was the only way around it.

Comment: Oh, ok. I'll defintely try that. Thanks.

Comment: Note, if you are not closing the files as in the comments on Angel's answer this won't help, just delay it a little.

Comment: see below, was the wrong place to answer ...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do you actually call "myFile.close()" at some point?

Comment: I'm not familiar with a "close()" method for a File in Java. I do use "myFile.delete()" though. Anyways I'm not writing to the file directly, I'm using the AWS SDK methods. the "getObject()" method writes the object from the S3 bucket directly to the file.

Comment: Deleting a File only deletes it from the directory it is in, it does not realy delete the inode and the blocks used IFF it is still open. So, do I get this right: you are not working with "Streams" or "Readers" or "Writers" which have a "close" method? Please check your documentation. Files need to be closed explicitely, they don'T close magically by themselves (unless the file object gets finalized, but that might enver happen).

Comment: That's the thing, I'm using a method from the AWS toolkit, that writes to the file, so I'm not using any readers or writers. I'm not sure it closes the stream, but I was assuming it does.

Comment: "they don't close magically by themselves"  unless you are using java 7 and the new try-with-resources, however doubt that the op is.

Comment: Well, if you could post some more source code we could help you browsing the documentation of AWS, but as we don't knwo what exyctly you are doing ...

Comment: OK, silly me... I found out that the methods I used did not close the stream, and I had to do it manually. Fixed the problem.
Thanks for the help guys.